# Creating your own string of characters as a private key, in public private key encryption?

Tags: php, security, encryption

We want to have sensitive data encrypted and stored in a database.  And when a user is viewing a form, if they are authorised to see this sensitive data, they will have an additional "password" that would decrypt the data for their session.

I was looking at public/private key encryption and using a human friendly password to generating the private key (sha hash etc) and the corresponding public key.  The public key would be used to encrypt new sensitive data entered.  And if users need to see the data they would enter the password ("private key") (in addition to having usual login account and permission settings).  This also avoids having the private key/password stored on any server.

Just using any random strings as a private key does not work:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
sha_hash('myPassword'.$salt)
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

So at the moment users would have to copy paste the private key text (made via openssl etc.) into a prompt to decrypt the info.  This would most likely mean people storing this key in a file or their email.

Is something like this possible?  Create my own private key string and then create a public key from that?

Comment: If you (or the client) is transmitting the private key anywhere, that kind of defeats the purpose of using public private key encryption. Are you sure this is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: This issue has no simple answer. I suggest you ask for help on the algorithm to be used in http://security.stackexchange.com/. You would need a KeyDerivationFunction to get a secret key from a password and use it with and encryption algorithm. Generating a key pair (public / private) to encrypt and decrypt is a different use case.

Comment: This is discussed at length [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1662/13022). It's possible, but I don't know of any PHP library that supports the use of a deterministic prime search for RSA. You could take the phpseclib source code and edit it to be deterministic.

Comment: It does not appear that you are using the unique attributes of public/private key encryption. It would seem that using a symmetric cipher such as AES along with a key derivation function would satisfy your needs better. Note a couple of disadvantages of public/private key encryption: 1. It is 100 to 100 times slower tan say AES and the data size is limited to the key size. It is not more secure.

Comment: Does the server decide in that moment whether or not the user has permission to see the data, and this is know about each user, or is the data encrypted ahead of time and it is the possession of the password that gives the user access, so any user that discovers the password, can see the data?

Comment: First user needs a login account (username, password, PIN). 2. They need access rights for the page.  3. They need password to see the specific sensitive data fields.

Answer (score 2):

> Is something like this possible? Create my own private key string and then create a public key from that?

Yes, it's possible in the abstract. No, it's not trivial with RSA, which requires prime numbers.

Example from [Halite](https://github.com/paragonie/halite) (which doesn't use RSA and is better off without RSA):

```
$salt = random_bytes(16); // Do this once, then make it a constant
$keyPair = KeyFactory::deriveEncryptionKeyPair(
    "My password",
    $salt,
    false, // This isn't a legacy key
    KeyFactory::SENSITIVE
);
$privateKey = $keyPair->getSecretKey();
$publicKey = $keyPair->getPublicKey();

var_dump(bin2hex($privateKey->getRawKeyMaterial()));
var_dump(bin2hex($publicKey->getRawKeyMaterial()));
```

Example output:

```
string(64) "030d6e4c462b2d15a48441cead4d1b9d0ae4a2ea6926a78e180a8b7d3ce6508f"
string(64) "189c86722bc81550186fd0eaba2a97d2e6c0a9c6f63a098cc1495309c7f9a71e"
```

These are ECDH keys over Curve25519, provided by libsodium.